# Convolution of random variables - what's wrong with this argument?

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables and $Z = X + Y$. Suppose $(X,Y)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\mu_2$ on $\mathbb R^2$. Then the joint density of $X,Y,Z$ (wrt a product measure of $\mu_2$ and the counting measure on $\mathbb R$) is given by
$$ p(x)p(y) \chi(x + y = z),$$
where $\chi$ is the indicator function. The marginal density of $Z$ is thus
$$ p(z) = \int \int p(x) p(y) \chi(x + y = z) dx dy = \int p(y) \left[ \int p(x) \chi_{x + y = z} dx \right] dy.$$
Since $p(x) \chi(x + y = z) = 0$ for all $x \ne z - y$, we have
$$\int p(x) \chi(x + y = z) dx = 0.$$
Thus $p(z) = 0$ everywhere. Obviously this is wrong, but where is the mistake?

EDIT: Andrew in the comments asked to justify why the joint density of $X,Y,Z$ is given by $p(x)p(y) \chi(x + y = z)$? That is, I need to prove that
$$ \Pr \left[ (X,Y,Z) \in A \right] = \int \int \int p(x) p(y) \chi(x + y = z) \chi([x,y,z] \in A) \nu (dz) dy dx,$$
for all $A \subset \mathbb R^3$, where $\nu$ is the counting measure.

Proof:
\begin{align*}
\Pr \left[ (X,Y,Z) \in A \right] &= \Pr \left[ (X,Y,X+Y) \in A \right] \\
&= \int \int p(x) p(y) \chi ( [x,y,x+y] \in A ) dy dx \\
&= \int \int \int p(x) p(y) \chi (x + y = z) \chi ( [x,y,z] \in A) \nu (dz) dy dx 
\end{align*}

I guess there is some problem here because the counting measure $\nu$ is not $\sigma$-finite so we cannot use Fubini-Tonelli or we cannot construct the product measure $\nu (dz) dy dx$ above. Any clarification on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that $\chi$ should be the dirac function, not the indicator function....

Comment: Why do you think the joint density of $X,Y,Z$ is what you wrote down?

Comment: $ \int \int p(x)p(y) \chi_{x + y = z}=0 dx dy$ for all $z$. How can $ p(x)p(y) \chi_{x + y = z}$ be a density function?

Comment: @AntonV. - good point. It depends what the dominating measure is. Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^2$ and $\nu$ the counting measure on $\mathbb R$. If the dominating measure is $\mu \times \nu$, then $\chi$ can be the indicator function.

Comment: @geetha290krm - following my comment above,  $\int \int \int p(x) p(y) \chi_{x + y = z} \nu(dz) dy dx = \int \int p(x) p (y) dy dx = 1$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang - see my edit to the question.

Comment: If X,Y are continuous RVs (say, with range $\mathbb R$, the reals) and Z=X+Y then simply the random vector (X,Y,Z) does not admit a joint continuous PDF (the probability measure is not absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue on $\mathbb R^3$: for example, the hyperplane $z=x+y$ has zero Lebesgue measure, but the corresponding $Z=X+Y$ happens with probability $1$).

Comment: @GiulioR - does it admit a density wrt some other measure? E.g. a product measure of the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^2$ and the counting measure on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: yes it is absolutely continuous wrt the following measure $m$ on $\mathbb R^3$:

$m(A):=$area of $A\cap\{z=x+y\}$.

This is what is usually meant by multiplying with a Dirac delta $\delta(z-x-y)$, as suggested in the first comment by Anton V.

Comment: Thank you @GiulioR Under this measure, why does my argument break down?

Comment: The third statement you write does not make sense to me (that the density of X,Y,Z wrt $\mu_2\otimes$ some counting measure exists and is given by that formula). One should prove such a statement, while in your Proof, the last equality does not make sense to me: $\chi(z=x+y)$ for any $z$ fixed selects ameasure zero set in the $x,y$ plane so the last integral is always zero.